# Missing storage after deleting boot camp partition

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, partition, storage

[image]

Using an iMac 27 inch - Late 2012. I deleted my bootcamp partition and lost 300gb. I didn't let it uninstall properly, rushed and closed the window and thats where all the errors and lost space problems stemmed from. Can anybody help me, I do not want to format my hard drive and lose everything because I can't back it up.

Answer (score 1):

Your APFS container is not the maximum size it can be.
You can expand the container to all the available free space using

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: For me 700+ GB of space went awol after innocently removing my windows partition via bootcamp, and thanks to you, I successfully recovered the missing 700+ GB Thanks!